# Airflow fails to add EMR step using EMRAddStep when HadoopJarStep arg has an argument ending with .json

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, amazon-emr

Looks like there is a bug in Airflow templated operator argument when it has any string that ends with *.json*. Does anyone know how to circumvent it? Following is my DAG - please notice **"--files", "s3://dummy/spark/application.json"** in the **STEPS** variable.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_create_job_flow import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_terminate_job_flow import EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_add_steps import EmrAddStepsOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr_job_flow import EmrJobFlowSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'Commscope',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['smishra@commscope.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False
}


JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    'Name': 'PiCalc',
    'ReleaseLabel': 'emr-5.29.0',
    'Instances': {
        'InstanceGroups': [
            {
                'Name': 'Master node',
                'Market': 'SPOT',
                'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
                'InstanceType': 'm1.medium',
                'InstanceCount': 1,
            }
        ],
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
        'TerminationProtected': False,
    },
    'JobFlowRole': 'EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    'ServiceRole': 'EMR_DefaultRole',
}

STEPS = [{
    "Name": "Process data",
    "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
        "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
        "Args": [
            "--class", "com.dummy.Application",
            "--files", "s3://dummy/spark/application.json",
            "--driver-java-options",
            "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties",
            "--driver-java-options",
            "-Dconfig.resource=application.json",
            "--driver-java-options"
            "s3://dummy/spark/app-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
            "application.json"
        ]
    }
}]

with DAG(
        dag_id='data_processing',
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
        start_date=days_ago(2),
        schedule_interval='0 3 * * *',
        tags=['inquire', 'bronze'],
) as dag:
    job_flow_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='launch_emr_cluster',
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default'
    )

    job_flow_sensor = EmrJobFlowSensor(
        task_id='check_cluster',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='launch_emr_cluster', key='return_value') }}",
        target_states=['RUNNING', 'WAITING'],
        aws_conn_id='aws_default'
    )

    proc_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='process_data',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='launch_emr_cluster', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=STEPS,
    )

    job_flow_terminator = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='terminate_emr_cluster',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='launch_emr_cluster', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        trigger_rule="all_done"
    )

    job_flow_creator >> job_flow_sensor >> proc_step >> job_flow_terminator
```

The cluster launches successfully but the **Airflow fails with following error**

```
[2020-08-21 15:06:42,307] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - s3://dummy/spark/application.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 964, in _run_raw_task
    self.render_templates(context=context)
...
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: s3://dummy/spark/application.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Airflow tried to renders all the values passed to template_fields. In your case as your are using `EmrAddStepsOperator`, it's template_fields are `['job_flow_id', 'job_flow_name', 'cluster_states', 'steps']`

**Source Code**: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/47c6657ce012f6db147fdcce3ca5e77f46a9e491/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr_add_steps.py#L48

This was added by https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8572

You can fix these in 2 ways:

1. Bypass this by adding an extra space after `.json` example `"s3://dummy/spark/application.json "`. This works because Airflow looks for each element in the Iterable to find if the string ends in `.json`
2. Subclass `EmrAddStepsOperator` and override the `template_ext` field. Example:

```py
class FixedEmrAddStepsOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_ext = ()
```

and then you can use this Operator:

```py
    proc_step = FixedEmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='process_data',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='launch_emr_cluster', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=STEPS,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow templating can be side-stepped pretty easily by adding an extra space at the end of the string, so long as the `EmrHook.add_job_flow_steps` will handle stripping the extra character:

```py
STEPS = [{
    "Name": "Process data",
    "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
        "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
        "Args": [
            "--class", "com.dummy.Application",
            "--files", "s3://dummy/spark/application.json ", # <-- Extra space
            "--driver-java-options",
            "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties",
            "--driver-java-options",
            "-Dconfig.resource=application.json",
            "--driver-java-options"
            "s3://dummy/spark/app-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
            "application.json"
        ]
    }
}]
```